# High CPU consumption on Add-SaveChangesAsync

Tags: .net, entity-framework

We are getting runaway threads under increased usage of our system. Solution is .net framework 6; EF 6.4.4, ASP.NET Web API.

In action filter, we perform logging of the request:

ActionFilter:

```
  public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteActionFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)
{
    //....
    
    _logsRepository.AddAsync(logRecord);
    }
```

LogsRepository:

```
 public class LogsRepository : ILogsRepository
    {
        private readonly IContext _context;

        public LogsRepository(IContext context) { _context = context; }

        public async Task AddAsync(LogModel log)
        {
        context.Logs.Add(logsRepositoryModel);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
```

After some time, CPU grows up and stays in high numbers with threads stuck. All frozen threads have the following stacktrace:

> mscorlib.dll!System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert+0xb9 EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityWrapperFactory.WrapEntityUsingStateManagerGettingEntry+0x1c0 EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.AddObject+0x8f EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet+0xd0
> EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add+0xab EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add+0x70
> PROJECT.dll!<...AddAsync>d__0.MoveNext+0x4d

This seems to indicate that EF is trying to track changes and since the db table/EF dbSet may get quite large (not sure about the second part as we save changes after each insert) it gets locked up somewhere.

EF model has properties marked as virtual. We also tried disabling AutoDetectChangesEnabled and ProxyCreationEnabled, but runaways continue to occur consistently.

Comment: What is IContext, and how are you managing its lifetime?  Looks like you're reusing long-lived DbContext instances and the ChangeTrackers are getting large.

Comment: container.RegisterType<System.Data.Entity.DbContext, ApplicationContext>(new PerThreadLifetimeManager());

Comment: That looks like a long-lived DbContext.  At a minimum remove all the Entries in the ChangeTracker after every SaveChanges().

Comment: Thank you both, it was through a chain of different objects with different lifetime managers that caused the context to be held between requests.